# como puedo solucionar este error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, entity-framework, nuget

estoy tratando de crear los models en C#por medio de Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
pero me marca el siguiente error

"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)"

el comando que estoy usando es el siguiente
scaffold-DbContext "Server=(AQk-TI11); Initial Catalog=DBAPI;Integrated Security=true" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutPutDir Models

Comment: Hola, no se cual puede ser el error pero aquí te dejo un enlace a otra pregunta con tu mismo caso. Suerte.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error

Answer (score 0):

puedes configurar tu conexion en, dependecias de servicios, para asegurarte que la conexion es correcta y en tu scaffold hacer referencia a esa conexion

dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold Name=ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer